# Can you help me identify this minifigure? masked face, green belt, black legs

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I'm trying to identify this minifigure for my son. It came from a bundle of mixed sets. I initially thought it was from the Super Heroes theme, but I've checked all the [Super Hero minifigures](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=768) on BrickLink and been unable to match it. Note, the minifigure's torso is blank on the back. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The **head** is [3626cpb1091](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb1091&idColor=90) AKA "Nightwing with red eyes". It only appears in one set, [76011-1 Man-Bat Attack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76011-1):

[image: blackwing minifig]

---

The **torso** is [973pb0714c01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0714c01&idColor=11) AKA "torso witch with green belt". It only appears in set [850487-1 "Halloween Accessory Set"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=850487-1) and as [a collectible minifigure from Series 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=col02-4):

[image: witch minifig]

---

The **legs** seem to be plain black legs, way too common to pinpoint their origin.

Comment: You missed the hands.